# Windows remote administration suite that doesn't rely on Active Directory, Domains, etc

Tags: windows, remote-access

I know there are a number of suites out there that allow Windows machines on a Domain, or in Active Directory to be remotely administrated (windows updates, program installs, maintenance, etc); but does there exist a package that does this for non-AD/Domain setups?

The kind of things I'm looking for:

- manage windows updates, + automatic applying
- custom package pushing (custom scripts, etc)
- general maintenance, visibily of health
- works for 2003/2008/2008R2
- works **without** Active Directory or being part of a Domain

Comment: If they're Windows clients, and they're not joined to a domain, then they're already in a workgroup. They may not all be in the same workgroup but making them so doesn't proffer any centralized management capability.

Comment: joeqwerty: having them in the workgroup "WORKGROUP" vs a named workgroup, I thought,  might help. That's ok, I've removed that confusing statement.

Comment: Not sure who gave this -1, but it seems a legit quality question, even discounting the "niceties" Active Directory gives.

Answer (score 1):

[Kaseya](http://www.kaseya.com/) and [N-able](http://www.n-able.com/features/) can be used to manage non-domain joined Windows clients.

Answer (score 1):

A WSUS server [can easily be configured](http://kudithipudi.org/2006/08/18/how-to-update-non-domain-members-using-wsus/)  as the update server for a workgroup machine.

System Center Operations Manager (SCOM) 2007 would do the job of monitoring health for all 3 operating systems, and can also be set up on [workgroup servers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nitgupta/archive/2009/09/28/what-does-it-take-to-monitor-servers-in-workgroup-from-scom.aspx)

For "packet pushing", depending on what that encompasses, System Center Configuration Manager (SCCM) might just do the job, also with [workgroup servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb680962.aspx).

You might want to wait a few weeks for the release of the new System Center 2012 suite, if you go with these options

Comment: Thanks Mathias, I've attempted to configure WSUS in the past, but it didn't fly. Will try SS(C/O)M.

Comment: WSUS is pretty easy - I don't think you'll find SCCM eaister to configure.